# CSV import using JPA

Tags: java, jpa, jdbc, persistence

Is JPA good for importing CSV data file into database?

Earlier i am using the JDBC to import CSV into database, so i am planning to change the persistence mechanism from JDBC to JPA, my CSV generally have 2000-5000 rows.

Comment: JPA is nothing to do with "CSV import". You have to have objects representing what is in the database. That is nothing to do with CSV

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends what is more important: easier to code and support or faster performance. JPA has a big memory overhead versus JDBC, but it's data model is easier to support.

Comment: I just did the batch import of a Map for 600 values (those were coming from JSP page) into database. Once I've reviewed the network timeline for both, JPA has some memory overhead... like 1120ms in JPA vs 600ms using JDBC.

Comment: What you say is performance issue, check memory overhead you can with any profiler (jvisualvm for example). But truly at the end all depends on project requirement.